# How to call a REST API from inside a Class definition

Tags: python, django, rest

I'm doing some RESTful API calls to an outside department and have written various functions (similar to the snippet below) that handle this based on what info I'm needing (e.g. "enrollment", "person", etc.). Now I'm left wondering if it wouldn't be more pythonic to put this inside of a class, which I believe would then make it easier to do processing such as "has_a_passing_grade", etc. and pass that out as an attribute or something when the class is instantiated.

Is there a standard way of doing this? Is it as easy as creating a class, somehow building the api_url as I'm doing below, call the api, parse and format the data, build a dict or something to return, and be done? And how would the call to such a class look? Does anyone have some example code similar to this that can be shared?

Thanks, in advance, for any help!

```
from django.utils import simplejson

try:
    api_url = get_api_url(request, 'enrollment', person_id)

    enrollment = call_rest_stop(key, secret, 'GET', api_url)

    enrollment_raw = enrollment.read()

    if enrollment_raw == '' or None:
        return 'error encountered', ''

    enrollment_recs = simplejson.loads(enrollment_raw)

    #  now put it in a dict
    for enrollment in enrollment_recs:
        coursework_dict = {
            'enrollment_id': enrollment['id'],
            ...,
        }
        coursework_list.append(coursework_dict)
    cola_enrollment.close()
except Exception, exception:
    return 'Error: ' + str(exception), ''
```

Comment: You've left out an important detail here: How do you want the code that uses your API to look? Add an example of that, since that is the most important aspect—the usability of your API comes before all other concerns, in my opinion. Once we know that, we can help you structure your code to answer those calls in the right way.

Comment: @DavidM, I suppose that's part of the question really. That's what I meant to ask with "And how would the call to such a class look?". I'm not yet very experienced with OOP, but I guess I'm imagining I would instantiate it by calling it with the needed lookup ID (e.g. student_ID in this case):

student_hist = Enrollment.get(pk=student_ID) [I know that syntax is off a bit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, let's say you want your API's users to call your API like so:

```
student_history, error_message = get_student_history(student_id)
```

You could then just wrap the above in that function:

```
from django.utils import simplejson

def get_student_history(person_id)
    try:
        api_url = get_api_url(request, 'enrollment', person_id)

        enrollment = call_rest_stop(key, secret, 'GET', api_url)

        enrollment_raw = enrollment.read()

        if enrollment_raw == '' or None:
            return [], 'Got empty enrollment response'

        enrollment_recs = simplejson.loads(enrollment_raw)

        #  now put it in a dict
        for enrollment in enrollment_recs:
            coursework_dict = {
                'enrollment_id': enrollment['id'],
                ...,
            }
            coursework_list.append(coursework_dict)
        cola_enrollment.close()

        return coursework_list, None
    except Exception as e:
        return [], str(exception)
```

You could also use a class, but keep in mind that you should only do that if there would be methods that those using your API would benefit from having. For example:

```
class EnrollmentFetcher(object):
    def __init__(person_id):
        self.person_id = person_id

    def fetch_data(self):
        self.coursework_list, self.error_message = get_student_history(self.person_id)

    def has_coursework(self):
        return len(self.coursework_list) > 0


fetcher = EnrollmentFetcher(student_id)
fetcher.fetch_data()
if fetcher.has_coursework():
    # Do something
```

Object-oriented programming is neither a good practice nor a bad one. You should choose to use it if it serves your needs in any particular case. In this case, it could help clarify your code (has_coursework is a bit clearer than checking if a list is empty, for example), but it may very well do the opposite.

Side note: Be careful about catching such a broad exception. Are you really okay with continuing if it's an OutOfMemory error, for example?

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'm afraid, however, that I must have presented this in a confusing manner. I'm already doing as you suggest...calling a function. What I'm really asking about is how to make it a class and use it as such. It may not make sense to do it that way, but thought I'd look at that now while still early in the project, hoping it may be more OOP in nature to use a class for this vs. a function.

Comment: I've added to my answer. Does that clarify?